# Make a dynamic variable without eval() corresponding to an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, forms

I am making a form to a string and so, using 2 arrays, I pass the required variables through to a function on the submit button being pressed (the name of the form element and the variable name).

But I'm using `eval()`, which isn't good, but I'm not good enough at objects or arrays to fix it.

My real question (although any insight is appreciated) is this: when a text box that corresponds to a radio button is checked, how do I get it to refer to the array and change the variable that gets changed from the array?

For example, if I have an array:

```
var examplearray = 
[
   "foo"
]
```

And onblur of the textbox =

```
maritalvar = document.getElementById('othermaritaltxt').value
```

How do I change `maritalvar` to be `foo`?

If possible could it search for `fo` to get `foo` so that it doesn't break if I add an element before it (assuming the use of `examplearray[0]`)?

Comment: Wow I didn't understand a thing... Can you post a jsfiddle or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use dynamic variables, use properties in an object.

Example:

```
var formData = {};
var fields = [ 'FirstName', 'LastName', 'Age' ];
for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
  var name = fields[i];
  formData[name] = document.getElementById(name).value;
}
```

Now the `formData` object has three properties, just as if you did:

```
var formdata = {
  'FirstName': document.getElementById('FirstName').value,
  'LastName': document.getElementById('LastName').value,
  'Age': document.getElementById('Age').value
};
```

Comment: could i use this in accordance with scripts so i could do all form detection(like with check boxes); really how would i get a function to return a value that would be accepted?